# INSERT INTO SELECT statement with more columns which is not in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Actually i have 2 tables Table A and Table B

Table A have 3 Columns such as A_a, A_b and A_c

Table B have 5 Columns such as B_a, B_b, B_c, B_d and B_e.

Here i Want to add First 3 column of Table B from Table A and Last 2 Column should be filled by Form.

So how it is possible.

I have tried INSERT INTO SELECT but for Last 2 Columns

Comment: What do you mean by "filled by form"?

Comment: you need to atleast show us their structure and data type

Comment: I dont think it is require...  @Ravi

Comment: @ChampDecay yes it is required.

Comment: I mean last two columns of row will filled by simple Insert query @Dai

Comment: Should we hold your hand and create the form for you too?

Comment: @ChampDecay was your problem solved ?

Comment: yes solved @Ravi..

Comment: @Ravi but Not by answer...

Answer (score 0):

You could use default filler

```
  INSERT INTO TABLEB(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, '', ''
  FROM TABLEA;
```

Now, instead of `''` you could pass any variable, which you get from application side.